# get transparency when I add negative pixels

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

When I am adding negative pixels to push my main menu over an image my main nav turns into transparency. I have no clue why. It seems like anything that is hovering over an image gets made translucent. You can see it here

http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/

Where would i go to edit it?

```
.nav-bar {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 56em;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look transparent to me, looks off-black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not transparent. The ribbon effects are sitting behind the image becuase of the negative `z-index`:

```
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
    ...
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I would also advise against using a top negative margin like that. It's sure to break on some devices. Better to place a large padding area on the menu and place that top image in the background for more reliable results.